# TiBasic Input function (I think)

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

Whether I try this code on a ti-84 plus ce or a ti-84 plus, I get a syntax error at the beginning:

```
ClrHome
Disp "Which unit?"
Disp "1. To Pascal"
Disp "2. To PSI"
Disp "3. To KPASS"
Input "Pick",UnitChoice

If UnitChoice=1
Then
    Input "Convert from PSI(1) or KPASS(2)", ConvertFromUnit
    If ConvertFromUnit=1
    Then
        Input "Give original value", OriginalValue
        Disp OriginalValue*6894.76
    Else
        Input "Give original value", OriginalValue
        Disp OriginalValue*1000
    End
End

If UnitChoice=2
Then
    Input "Convert from what unit (1 for PASCAL, 2 for KPAS)", ConvertFromUnit
    If ConvertFromUnit=1
    Then
        Input "Give original value", OriginalValue
        Disp OriginalValue*0.000145038
    Else
        Input "Give original value", OriginalValue
        Disp OriginalValue*0.145038
    End
End

If UnitChoice=3
Then
    Input "Convert from what unit (1 for PSI, 2 for PASCAL)", ConvertFromUnit
    If ConvertFromUnit=1
    Then
        Input "Give original value", OriginalValue
        Disp OriginalValue*6.89476
    Else
        Input "Give original value", OriginalValue
        Disp OriginalValue*0.001
    End
End
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you *literally* wrote, because this code is not really possible in TI-BASIC (then again maybe that's the problem), E: you may also be interested in the `Menu(` command

Comment: @harold I have added all the code I had for this in the original post

Comment: OK if this is literally the code, then this applies: [Naming a BASIC variable (TI-84) with multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18523883/555045) (you can only use the pre-defined names, unless it's a list). Also indentation is not possible, unless you're very desperate and use something like `"    ":Disp X` (with a string literal and a colon to separate it from the next command) but that changes the `Ans` variable and doesn't even look good

Comment: @harold I have again changed the original code and it lets me input a number now,  but when I do it gives me another syntax. So it displays the first part and when I enter in "1" for example, it hits me with an error.

Comment: Nevermind I looked over it myself fixed a couple of things and it works as I need it to, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and take the [tour], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. For future questions: 1) Please do not edit code in the question to show the "solved" version. It's important for questions to reflect code that causes the problem, so that people who have the same question can verify that they are in the right place and so that people who want to answer can properly understand the problem. When you show code in a question, it does not matter if it reflects your own code; it matters if it reflects **what you are asking about**.

Comment: 2) Make sure that the question is about **one** problem and is **focused** on the specific part that causes that problem, by working to create a [mre]. Keep in mind that posts here are **questions, not** requests [for help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236); the site's purpose is not to get your code to work, but to **build a searchable, reference Q&A library** that everyone can use. 3) Keep in mind that the post should be **about the question, not** you, your level of skill, or why you are writing the program. We [remove](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/) such commentary.

Comment: 4) While it's good to try to solve the problem yourself first, this is not about trying to "deserve" an answer. Simply telling us about things that you tried does not help to understand **the question**. Instead, show, don't tell - write a question that **reflects what you learned** from those attempts, by using that information to i) clarify why your question is different from [existing Stack Overflow questions that might look similar](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252/); ii) [locate](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had to get rid of the indentation and change the variables to simples variables that were for ti basic rather than custom ones I was trying to use. I was able to find help from another user on here who walked me through the process.